# How to properly annotate a List<Interface> with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.1

I'm just starting to learn how to use Hibernate and I'm not be able to figure out how to properly annotate a list when it's referencing an interface.

This is my case, I have a class MarketOrderImpl that implements MarketOrder like so...

```
@Entity
public final class MarketOrderImpl implements MarketOrder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;
private OrderType type;
private BigDecimal price;
private BigDecimal quantity;
private BigDecimal total;

public MarketOrderImpl(OrderType type, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal 
quantity, BigDecimal total) {
    this.type = type;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.total = total;
}
```

and I have an MarketOrderBookImpl that has two lists that I'm not being able to anotate without an exception (private List sellOrders and private List buyOrders)

```
@Entity
public final class MarketOrderBookImpl implements MarketOrderBook {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String marketId;

@OneToMany @JoinTable(name="marketorderimpl")
@MapKeyColumn(name="id")
private List<MarketOrder> sellOrders;

@OneToMany @JoinTable(name="marketorderimpl")
@MapKeyColumn(name="id")
private List<MarketOrder> buyOrders;


public MarketOrderBookImpl(String marketId, List<MarketOrder> 
sellOrders, List<MarketOrder> buyOrders) {
    this.marketId = marketId;
    this.sellOrders = sellOrders;
    this.buyOrders = buyOrders;
}
```

This is my exception...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:br.com.codefleck.tradebot.exchanges.trading.api.impl.MarketOrderBookImpl.sellOrders[br.com.codefleck.tradebot.tradingapi.MarketOrder]at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1136) at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:792)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:727)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ... 66 more
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Mohammad I disagree, that is a different question as it is about mapping and multiplicity between different entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a *PersistenceProvider* implementation - such as Hibernate - can't infer which concrete class is the "correct" one to use in such a case, you have to tell the ORM implementation what type to use at runtime.

In section 11.1.40 (PDF page 474) of the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) we find an important piece of information, related to your question:

> The entity **class** that is the target
>   of the association. Optional only if the collection-valued
>   relationship property is
>   defined using Java generics. Must be specified
>   otherwise.

*Hint*:

Table 37 on "`OneToMany` Annotation Elements" lists further details on how to programmatically declare **runtime information** for a specific OR mapper.

Given the above information, the correct approach is to declare runtime-related information for the **targetEntity** type with:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity= MarketOrderImpl.class) 
@JoinTable(name="marketorderimpl")
@MapKeyColumn(name="id")
private List<MarketOrder> sellOrders;

@OneToMany(targetEntity= MarketOrderImpl.class) 
@JoinTable(name="marketorderimpl")
@MapKeyColumn(name="id")
private List<MarketOrder> buyOrders;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define target entity so hibernate can understand which domain to bind this relation.

`@OneToMany(targetEntity=MarketOrderImpl.class)
 @JoinTable(name="marketorderimpl")
@MapKeyColumn(name="id")
private List<MarketOrder> sellOrders;`